# Table creation on Access 97' database - How to enable Unicode Compression

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm creating a table in an existing Access 97' database with the following command:

```
OleDbCommand cmd_createPlaylistNames2 = new OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE PlaylistNames2 ([Anagnorisi] long, [PlaylistName] TEXT(50) WITH COMPRESSION, [PlaylistMaker] TEXT(50) WITH COMPRESSION," +
            " [Duration] TEXT(50) WITH COMPRESSION, [Comments] TEXT(50), [FromAutomation] BIT, Primary Key (Anagnorisi))", con);
```

I then fill the table with data from a dataset. When I open the database with Office the fields I have set as WITH COMPRESSION have the Unicode Compression property set to No. 
Any ideas why is this happening ?

EDIT:

Nevermind, I've set the fields to Unicode Compression with DAO.

```
dao.DBEngine dbeng = new dao.DBEngine();
dao.Workspace wrkspc = dbeng.CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", dao.WorkspaceTypeEnum.dbUseJet);
dao.Database db = wrkspc.OpenDatabase("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Merge2\\playlists.MDB", false, false, "");
dao.TableDef tabledef = db.TableDefs["PlaylistNames"];
dao.Field name = tabledef.Fields["PlaylistName"];
dao.Field maker = tabledef.Fields["PlaylistMaker"];
dao.Field duration = tabledef.Fields["Duration"];
dao.Field comments = tabledef.Fields["Comments"];

dao.Property propName = name.CreateProperty("UnicodeCompression", 1, -1, false);
name.Properties.Append(propName);

dao.Property propMaker = maker.CreateProperty("UnicodeCompression", 1, -1, false);
maker.Properties.Append(propMaker);

dao.Property propDuration = duration.CreateProperty("UnicodeCompression", 1, -1, false);
duration.Properties.Append(propDuration);

dao.Property propComments = comments.CreateProperty("UnicodeCompression", 1, -1, false);
comments.Properties.Append(propComments);

wrkspc.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Access 97 uses Jet 3.5; 16-bit storage of text was introduced in Jet 4.0.  So whatever the value of your UnicodeCompression flag, if the database version is less than 4, you'll find the file is using one-byte characters.

Comment: @Pantelis but if the file is an Access 97 database, then it is in Jet 3.5 format.  It is the file format that dictates whether unicode compression is relevant, since unicode compression controls the way characters are stored in the file.  You may use Jet 4.0 to read a Jet 3 file, of course, but you will notice that text data seems to change if you change the computer's code page, because of the translation between the single-byte characters in the Jet 3 file and the double-byte characters in the Jet 4 library.